# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte error

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, urllib

I'm trying to get a response from `urllib` and decode it
to a readable format. The text is in Hebrew and also contains characters like `{` and `/`

top page coding is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

raw string is:

```
b'\xff\xfe{\x00 \x00\r\x00\n\x00"\x00i\x00d\x00"\x00 \x00:\x00 \x00"\x001\x004\x000\x004\x008\x003\x000\x000\x006\x004\x006\x009\x006\x00"\x00,\x00\r\x00\n\x00"\x00t\x00i\x00t\x00l\x00e\x00"\x00 \x00:\x00 \x00"\x00\xe4\x05\xd9\x05\xe7\x05\xd5\x05\xd3\x05 \x00\xd4\x05\xe2\x05\xd5\x05\xe8\x05\xe3\x05 \x00\xd4\x05\xea\x05\xe8\x05\xe2\x05\xd4\x05 \x00\xd1\x05\xde\x05\xe8\x05\xd7\x05\xd1\x05 \x00"\x00,\x00\r\x00\n\x00"\x00d\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00"\x00 \x00:\x00 \x00[\x00]\x00\r\x00\n\x00}\x00\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00\n\x00'
```

Now I'm trying to decode it using:

```
 data = data.decode()
```

and I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 16):

Your problem is that that is not UTF-8. You have **UTF-16** encoded data, decode it as such:

```
>>> data = b'\xff\xfe{\x00 \x00\r\x00\n\x00"\x00i\x00d\x00"\x00 \x00:\x00 \x00"\x001\x004\x000\x004\x008\x003\x000\x000\x006\x004\x006\x009\x006\x00"\x00,\x00\r\x00\n\x00"\x00t\x00i\x00t\x00l\x00e\x00"\x00 \x00:\x00 \x00"\x00\xe4\x05\xd9\x05\xe7\x05\xd5\x05\xd3\x05 \x00\xd4\x05\xe2\x05\xd5\x05\xe8\x05\xe3\x05 \x00\xd4\x05\xea\x05\xe8\x05\xe2\x05\xd4\x05 \x00\xd1\x05\xde\x05\xe8\x05\xd7\x05\xd1\x05 \x00"\x00,\x00\r\x00\n\x00"\x00d\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00"\x00 \x00:\x00 \x00[\x00]\x00\r\x00\n\x00}\x00\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00\n\x00'
>>> data.decode('utf16')
'{ \r\n"id" : "1404830064696",\r\n"title" : "פיקוד העורף התרעה במרחב ",\r\n"data" : []\r\n}\r\n\r\n'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(data.decode('utf16'))
{'title': 'פיקוד העורף התרעה במרחב ', 'id': '1404830064696', 'data': []}
```

If you loaded this from a website with `urllib.request`, the `Content-Type` header *should* contain a `charset` parameter telling you this; if `response` is the returned `urllib.request` response object, then use:

```
codec = response.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
```

This defaults to UTF-8 when no `charset` parameter has been set, which is the appropriate default for JSON data.

Alternatively, use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) to load the JSON response, it handles decoding automatically (including UTF-codec autodetection specific to JSON responses).

One further note: the [PEP 263 source code codec comment](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) is used *only* to interpret your source code, including string literals. It has nothing to do with encodings of external sources (files, network data, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in `Django` with `Python 3.4`. I was trying to get this to work with [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

This was my code that fixed the error **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte error**.

This is the passing test:

```
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
import uuid
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class AttachmentTests(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.base_dir = dirname(dirname(dirname(__file__)))

        self.image = join(self.base_dir, "source/test_in/aaron.jpeg")
        self.image_filename = os.path.split(self.image)[1]

    def test_create_image(self):
        id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        with open(self.image, 'rb') as data:
            # data = data.read()
            post_data = {
                'id': id,
                'filename': self.image_filename,
                'file': data
            }

            response = self.client.post("/api/admin/attachments/", post_data)

            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```